# Kafka node disconnected - what do these high-frequency repeated errors mean and how to solve them?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I use a Kafka producer within a Spring Boot application.

```java
@Component
public class MessageProducer {

    @Value("${topic.name}")
    private String topic;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<Integer, String> kafkaTemplate;

    public void produceMessage(String msg) {
        kafkaTemplate.send(topic, msg);
    }
}
```

I have configure the following properties in Spring boot configuration file `application.properties`:

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=...
topic.name=...
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
spring.kafka.properties.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="..." password="...";
```

When I call produceMessage, the log fills continuously with such messages:

```
2023-11-17T17:09:39.032+01:00  INFO 35184 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -5 disconnected.
2023-11-17T17:09:39.032+01:00  INFO 35184 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 0 due to node -5 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 170ms, elapsed time since send: 170ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2023-11-17T17:09:39.032+01:00  WARN 35184 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker broker-105.server:9093 (id: -5 rack: null) disconnected
2023-11-17T17:09:39.134+01:00  INFO 35184 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -3 disconnected.
2023-11-17T17:09:39.135+01:00  INFO 35184 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 1 due to node -3 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 270ms, elapsed time since send: 270ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2023-11-17T17:09:39.135+01:00  WARN 35184 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker broker-103.server:9093 (id: -3 rack: null) disconnected
2023-11-17T17:09:39.301+01:00  INFO 35184 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -9 disconnected.
2023-11-17T17:09:39.301+01:00  INFO 35184 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 2 due to node -9 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 55ms, elapsed time since send: 55ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2023-11-17T17:09:39.301+01:00  WARN 35184 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker broker-109.server:9093 (id: -9 rack: null) disconnected
2023-11-17T17:09:39.493+01:00  INFO 35184 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-11-17T17:09:39.493+01:00  INFO 35184 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 3 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 84ms, elapsed time since send: 84ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2023-11-17T17:09:39.493+01:00  WARN 35184 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker broker-101.server:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2023-11-17T17:09:39.494+01:00  INFO 35184 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -7 disconnected.
2023-11-17T17:09:39.494+01:00  INFO 35184 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 4 due to node -7 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 83ms, elapsed time since send: 83ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2023-11-17T17:09:39.494+01:00  WARN 35184 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker broker-107.server:9093 (id: -7 rack: null) disconnected
2023-11-17T17:09:39.810+01:00  INFO 35184 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -6 disconnected.
2023-11-17T17:09:39.810+01:00  INFO 35184 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 6 due to node -6 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 204ms, elapsed time since send: 204ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2023-11-17T17:09:39.810+01:00  WARN 35184 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker broker-106.server:9093 (id: -6 rack: null) disconnected
2023-11-17T17:09:39.811+01:00  INFO 35184 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -2 disconnected.
2023-11-17T17:09:39.811+01:00  INFO 35184 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 5 due to node -2 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 206ms, elapsed time since send: 206ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2023-11-17T17:09:39.811+01:00  WARN 35184 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker broker-102.server:9093 (id: -2 rack: null) disconnected
2023-11-17T17:09:39.974+01:00  INFO 35184 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -8 disconnected.
2023-11-17T17:09:39.975+01:00  INFO 35184 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 7 due to node -8 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 52ms, elapsed time since send: 52ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2023-11-17T17:09:39.975+01:00  WARN 35184 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker broker-108.server:9093 (id: -8 rack: null) disconnected
2023-11-17T17:09:40.137+01:00  INFO 35184 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -4 disconnected.
2023-11-17T17:09:40.137+01:00  INFO 35184 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 8 due to node -4 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 54ms, elapsed time since send: 54ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2023-11-17T17:09:40.137+01:00  WARN 35184 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker broker-104.server:9093 (id: -4 rack: null) disconnected
2023-11-17T17:09:40.304+01:00  INFO 35184 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -5 disconnected.
2023-11-17T17:09:40.304+01:00  INFO 35184 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 9 due to node -5 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 58ms, elapsed time since send: 58ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix **all** kafka values with `spring.kafka`. [See docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.kafka).

Also, `sasl.mechanism=PLAIN` seems to contradict `security.protocol=SASL_SSL`. Did you want `SASL_PLAINTEXT`?

---

The error simply means the bootstrap servers are unable to connect, and the producer is trying to connect to each of the 9 brokers in your values `broker-101`-`broker-109` for any initial connection.

It could also mean the SASL config is wrong (username/password).

Since you are trying to use `SASL_SSL`, this means you also need to set values like `spring.kafka.properties[ssl.key.password]`, `spring.kafka.properties[ssl.keystore.location]`, etc.

It could also mean the `advertised.listeners` are incorrect on the server-side properties for the connection protocol you're using from the client.

---

You should try to use `kafka-console-producer` with the same settings to verify the connection does work before moving onto Spring client.

---

Here's a tutorial from Confluent on configuration of Spring Boot for Confluent Cloud, or a local Kafka.

https://developer.confluent.io/get-started/spring-boot/#introduction

Comment: "sasl.mechanism=PLAIN seems to contradict security.protocol=SASL_SSL. Did you want SASL_PLAINTEXT?" it's what I've been told to use by the kafka admin so I must raise that it's contradictory. It seems all these properties need to be set?
spring.kafka.properties.ssl.truststore.location
spring.kafka.properties.ssl.truststore.password
spring.kafka.properties.ssl.keystore.location
spring.kafka.properties.ssl.keystore.password
spring.kafka.properties.ssl.key.password
Also they pointed me to a dozen of crt and p7c files, can I also use those file types ?

Comment: Without knowing how your Kafka server is setup, I cannot answer what properties are necessary. If you use ssl, then those all should be set, yes. For file types, refer Kafka documentation itself. I think only JKS, p12 and crt files are allowed